# How to apply Search term in Jquery Datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using Jquery datatable and I want that if I search for "car", it needs to highlight "Car", "CAR", "caR", "C a-r" "C -ar" and so on. Currently if I search for car it does not display Ca-r or C -ar. How can I achieve this? Please help thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I never used datatable before, I didnot found any point from where I should start this. I just simply applied datatable for now. Any link of help via code would be appreciated

Comment: Have a look [there](https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html) then.

Comment: This can be solved in several very different ways.  What solution to choose depends on the answers to 1) how is the dataTable initiallised, what is the source of data 2) does this inflict all or most of the columns, or is it isolated to one or two columns who need special treatment?  3) one thing is filtering, but what about sorting / ordering?

Comment: #davidkonrad -- 1) it's data is coming from database. 2)it only has one column 3) sorting, pagination, ordering is set to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own custom filtering function to handle situations like this:

```js
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
    // apply your custom filtering logic here
  }
);

$('#datatable_filter input').keyup(function() {
  table.draw(); // Redraw the table when the search input field is changed
});
```

Please see documentation [here](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html), and an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/47th8bts/1/).

**Extended answer:**

There is nothing particularly clever going on here, the code is just stripping out any `spaces` and `hyphens` from the data in the table cells and doing a comparison based on that. If you need something more robust, you will need to look into `regular expressions`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();

  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(

    function (settings, data, dataIndex) {        
    var origInput = $('#search').val().toLowerCase();        
    var input = $('#search').val().replace(/\ /g, '').toLowerCase();        
    var strSearch = data.toString();
    
    strSearch = strSearch.replace(/\ /g, '');
    strSearch = strSearch.replace(/\-/g, '');

    if (input.length == 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (data.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(origInput) >= 0) {            
        return true;        
    } else if (strSearch.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) >= 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});

  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    table.draw(); // Redraw the table when the search input field is changed
  });
});
```

Updated demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/47th8bts/10/).

Comment: #Ash can you please guide me how can i search record like the why i mentioned above with this given code by you. Thanks

Comment: @UmairMalik please see my updated answer and demo. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks #Ash this is exactly what I want, but it is not working like its working here. here is my site's link:- http://ranaapp.zz.vc/search_table/search.php, it has a word c -ar in it, so when you search for car it should display that too but it is not.

Comment: You are using the default search box. Check my demo again, you will see that I have created a new search box and hidden the default DataTables one. You will need to do this to overwrite the default functionality.

Comment: yes you are right, I created a new search box but it didn't worked well again and think it is bcoz the code you created work only if there is one word in td, while in my case word car(or any other word) can be any where within that string. so i guess this approach wont work in my case. :/

Comment: i need something that will search through entire record in table, ignore special character within word that is typed in search field and then display the result. :/

Comment: I've update my answer and demo. Please take a look. As I mentioned in my post, if this doesn't fit your requirement you may need to look into regular expressions.